# Does $EXP\neq ZPP$ imply sub-exponential simulation of BPP or NP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, reference-request, complexity-classes, conditional-results

By simulation I mean in the Impaglazzio-Widgerson [IW98] sense, i.e. sub-exponential deterministic simulation which appears correct i.o to every efficient adversary.

I think this is a proof: if $EXP\neq BPP$ then from [IW98] we get that BPP has such a simulation. Otherwise we have that $EXP=BPP$, which implies $RP=NP$ (because $NP \subseteq BPP$) and $EXP \in PH$. Now if $NP=RP=ZPP$ we have that $PH$ collapses to $ZPP$ and as a result $EXP$, but this cannot happen because of the assumption, so $RP\neq ZPP$ and this by the Kabanets paper "Easiness assumptions and hardness tests: trading time for zero error" implies that RP has such a simulation and as a result also NP.

This sounds like it could be a useful gap theorem.  Does anyone know if it appears anywhere?

Comment: Very interesting.  I haven't seen this argument before, but I'm not by any means an expert in these things...

Comment: (Just for reference): Identical question on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/35945/. Maybe someone finds the comments there inspiring.

Comment: Why does NP in ZPP imply PH in ZPP?

Comment: ZPP is closed under complement, and contained in NP. So, $\mathrm{NP\subseteq ZPP}$ implies NP = ZPP = coNP, hence PH = NP = ZPP.